# Jenkins Build-flow + Email-ext, mail not sent

Tags: email, build-process, jenkins-plugins

I'm new to Jenkins. I use [build-flow plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Flow+Plugin) for parallel jobs and [email-ext plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin) for sending mail. The issue is that email-ext not sent e-mails.
Here is my DSL for build-flow:

```
parallel (
  {
    ignore(FAILURE){ build("Firefox_job") }
    ignore(FAILURE){ build("IE10_job") }
  },
  {
    ignore(FAILURE){ build("Chrome_job") }
    ignore(FAILURE){ build("IE11_job") }
  }
)
```

What I need is to get an e-mail notification with links to "index.html" for each job, e.g.

```
$DEFAULT_CONTENT

Check the test results at:
http://***/job/Chrome_job/ws/target/surefire-reports/index.html
http://***/job/Firefox_job/ws/target/surefire-reports/index.html
http://***/job/IE10_job/ws/target/surefire-reports/index.html
http://***/job/IE11_job/ws/target/surefire-reports/index.html
```

As a workaround I could perform this sending for each job in DSL and then I get 4 e-mails. Also I could create seperate job which just sent all this links, but this job will be always success and I need notification only if failure. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just use a trigger for "failure"-if any   only rather than using Plain Email_ext feature.

Hope this helps @user3535807